# GWT ScrollTable performance problem

Tags: performance, gwt

I'm having a little performance problem with the gwt (incubator) ScrollTable. It's rendering really slow. Not even when I'm loading a lot of data - it happens already with a few rows.
Or is it possible that the deserializing of the data takes so long?

I'm using GWT 2.0 and IE.

Maybe someone has the same problem or a solution for it.

Thx and Happy Easter!

Answer (score 0):

Please post your code - without it it's only possible to guess.

Nevertheless, you might try using [Speed Tracer](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/speedtracer/) in Chrome (or Firebug in Firefox, though it doesn't have quite as detailed timing information) to see what's taking the time.